# Not able to pass input value of a form through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that is responsible to perform a search ([@fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/learner001/erdn0h97/))

```
<form class="pull-right" id="generate" >
    <input type="text" id="name" class="search-query">
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Find</button>
</form>
```

When the search will get performed the result should get displayed in this div

```
<div id="prod_search">                          
</div>
```

To perform the search i want to pass the value entered in the input field of the form to another script(t_searchmenu.php) through ajax

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $("#generate").submit(function(e){
 var name= $(this).find('#name').val();;
  alert(name);
  $.ajax({
     type:"post",
     url:"t_searchmenu.php",
     data:{"name":name},
     cache:false,
     success: function(returndata){
       $('#prod_search').html(returndata);
        console.log(returndata)
     }
   }); 
   return false;
});
</script>
```

t_searchmenu.php code

```
<?php
$name =  $_REQUEST['name']; 
 echo $name;
?>
```

But the issue is that i am not getting any result or error in console.

Note: In fiddle the value is getting displayed inside alert box, but for some reason it is not getting displayed in my webpage

Comment: "i am not getting any result or error in console" change your console error log settings

Comment: or use simple jquery `var name=$('#name').val();` as you are already using jquery

Comment: You should not change the code, keep `getElementByID` as it is

Comment: @MKA  tried your way, but still not getting desired result

Comment: Try my way down . It May help @st001

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `D` in `getElementByID` should be lowercase. `getElementByID` is invalid syntax.

Use `getElementById`(note lowercase `d`) not `getElementByID`.

```
var name= document.getElementById('name').value;
```

I'd also suggest to use jQuery approach

```
var name= $('#name').val();
```

In case if you have duplicate id,

```
var name= $(this).find('#name').val();
```

Also, add `name` to `input`

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="search-query">
```

Comment: i tried your code, but still i am getting same result

Comment: @st001 Is the request sent to the server, do you get the variables sent in REQUEST

Comment: @st001 Try with absolute URL, instead of relative URL

Comment: i tried the only thing that is changing in the entire page is its url, the url gets changed from www.example.com/index.php  to www.example.com/index.php?

Comment: plz tel me one thing, if i try to check the value inside var name through alert box, will it show value?

Comment: i tried this alert(name); after var name= $(this).find('#name').val(); but its not displaying anything

Comment: i have added a fiddle and updated my post, can u plz go thru it once again

Comment: yes its working there but i am not getting the alert box on my page, and the value in request i  don't think i am getting it as it is not getting printed in console

Comment: i made few changes, now the value of name is getting passed in the url of index page(same page), but it should have gone to t_searchmenu.php pageand should have returned data from there back to index page isn't it??

Comment: used absolute url, but still the values are getting passed to same page url

Answer (score 0):

You must change

```
document.getElementByID('name').value;
```

to

```
document.getElementById('name').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#generate").submit(function(e){
   var name= document.getElementById('name').value;
  $.ajax({
     type:"post",
     url:"test2.php",
     data:{"name":name},
     cache:false,
     success: function(html){
       $('#prod_search').html(html);  // here `html` come not `returndata`
        console.log(html)
     }
   });
   return false;
});
```

your ajax return data is stored in `html` in success function parameter so you have to use `html` instead of `returndata`

Comment: i tried your code, but i am still not getting the desired result

Comment: put your filename in url. may be you not changed it.

Comment: did so but didnt work, plz tel me one thing, if i try to check the value inside var name through alert box, will it show value?

Comment: yes i have, i have also added js fiddle and also updated my post can u plz have a look at it once more

Comment: your t_searchmenu.php file in the same folder or what??

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `serialize()` method on form to pass its value.

```
$("#generate").serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code -

```js
<script>
$("#generate").submit(function(e){
   var name= document.getElementById('name').value;
  $.ajax({
     type:"post",
     url:"t_searchmenu.php",
     data:{"name":name},
     cache:false,
     success: function(returndata){
       $('#prod_search').html(returndata);
        console.log(returndata)
     }
   });
   return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: i tried but it displayed no result, plz tel me one thing, if i try to check the value inside var name through alert box, will it show value?

Comment: @st001 - Yes, it should show the value. Could you please try that and share what you are observing in alert box?